Camera not showing or showing a black screen (rtmp_braodcaster) flutter
When using the rtmp_broadcaster package, the camera preview does not show or shows a black screen on my Huawei Nova 3i (Android 9.0).
Steps to Reproduce:
Initialize the rtmp_broadcaster package in a Flutter application.
Set up the CameraController to preview the camera feed.
Run the app on Huawei Nova 3i (Android 9.0).
The camera preview is either not shown or shows a black screen.
The camera preview should display the live feed from the device camera.
Device: Huawei Nova 3i
Android Version: 9.0
rtmp_broadcaster Version: 2.2.6
Flutter Version: 3.19.3
